# canvas js: how to remove a datapoint dynamically but without creating a "hole" in chart?

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

After hours and hours playing with canvasJS I couldn't find a way to dynamically remove points from my chart in an elegant way.
What I want to do is to allow users to select/deselect data he want to see plotted. For instance, on a chart that shows data from Jan/2014 to Dec/2014 (axis X), if the user choose not to show Feb/2014, I iterate thru dataPoints, remove such point and call render(). The column with data corresponding to February then disappear, but on X axis, the label for February is still shown, creating a "hole".
If First or Last item is deselected, then the result is OK, such month is not displayed.
I have tried using Date() for x, tried using Integers for x and formatting the Date as a label but none worked for me.
So, before starting looking for another solution I would like to know if you guys could help me out figuring what I`m doing wrong.
Best regards!!

Comment: Could you show us some code so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through the question and created an example. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/jsyebk44/)

Here is the logic which I used:

```
for(var i=0; i<dataPoints.length ; i++){
        var dp = dataPoints[i];
        var dataPointMonth = (new Date(dp.label).getMonth());
        if( dataPointMonth !== monthToHide){
            dp.x = index++;
            newDataPoints.push(dp);
        }
}
```

You can use [labels](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/label/) instead of x value in this case and use [formatDate](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/format-date/) method in order to format date values as required and use [labelFormatter](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/label-formatter/) for further customization.

```
labelFormatter : function ( e ) {
            return CanvasJS.formatDate( e.label, "MMM");  
}
```